# Change URL while loading it in browser - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have created an app that will load links from my server into the webview. However, I have also written an intent to open the link in the user's browser so they can download the file. I want the link to change a bit while it loads in the browser.

I.e:

This is the link : https://www.example/v/file

My app should change "v" to "f" and load in the user's browser.

Like this: https://www.example/f/file

My code:

```
    private void initWebDowload(String s){

        webView.loadUrl(s);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(s));
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kinda complicated but you need to attach a custom WebViewClient to your WebView so you can change the URL loading behaviour.

Just to give an example:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // right here you are given the chance to change the [url] ^
        view.loadUrl(url.replace("/v/file", "/f/file")); // replace v with f
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, will try to use this.